# Why Messages are not sent in order in Messenger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am getting messages not in sequence please tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

```
    let sendMessage = (sender_psid, response) => {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            let request_body = {
                "recipient": {
                    "id": sender_psid
                },
                "message": {
                    "text": response
                }
            }
            
            request({
                "uri": "https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me/messages",
                "qs": { "access_token": PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
                "method": "POST",
                "json": request_body
            }, (error, response, body) => {
                if (error) { console.log("Error sending message: " + response.error); return reject(response.error); }
                else if (response.body.error) { console.log('Response body Error: ' + response.body.error); return reject(response.body.error); }
    
                console.log("Message sent successfully to " + sender_psid); 
                return resolve(response);
            });
        });
    };

sendMessage(sender_psid, "Message 1")
.then(sendMessage(sender_psid,"Message 2"));
```

**Output**

> Message 1 Message 2

> Message 2 Message 1

Comment: I don't see console.log that output `response` as you indicated in Output section. Please change `response` parameter name in either `sendMessage` definition or in `(error, response, body)` callback definition

Comment: @Anatoly It is giving output in messenger chat window

Comment: It can be some kind of queue on Facebook side or simultaneous processing that does not guarantee that messages appear in the same order you sent them.

Comment: @Anatoly Problem is that next message is posted before promise get resolved. But I dont know how to send message after successfull message sent of first message

Comment: Did you added the message content itself to `console.log("Message sent successfully to " + sender_psid); `to make sure?

Comment: `.then(sendMessage(…))` needs to be `.then(firstResponse => { return sendMessage(…); })` - pass a function to be executed later, don't call it immediately and pass a promise.

Comment: @Bergi Tysm for the solution . You saved me :)